# How to call a javascript function through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i know this question is a bit silly, i am building a tool for my assignment.This tool takes the form from a website and its js files etc. My problem is that i have been told to call the javascript function by AJAX, the javascript which does the validation..

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is the js function

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
   alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

how can i use AJAX to call the validateForm() function ??

Comment: Why would you use ajax to call a client side function?

Comment: why ajax to call a method?

Comment: its a requirement in the assignment...Do you have any idea how to do it,i know javascript is already doing the job

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use AJAX to call the validation function. If it's a requirement, you should tell your instructor that they don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @John you may want to explain to your teacher/boss that AJAX is redundant here because unless you need a server response, you're just wasting resources.

Comment: Maybe your validateForm is supposed to be on server-side and you should call it with AJAX?

Comment: yeah my function is in a js file on my server..So how can i do it ??

Comment: Are you running a server at all? Nodejs?

Comment: I'm thinking the assignment is poorly worded, and that the `validateForm` function should then make an AJAX request to the server when the form is valid. Is this true, @John?

Comment: Why do you think you need an ajax request? surely the assignment doesn't call out ajax specifically

Comment: @GregBurghardt ya something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an ajax to a js file in your server, you can use this with jQuery:

```
$.getScript( "./somefile.js" )
 .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
   console.log( textStatus );
 })
 .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
  // some code if it fails
});
```

And always consult the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: this code makes sense but how can i call it, am not good at jQuery

Comment: Just add that code after document.onload
or in jQuery 
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //code here
});

So it runs right after the page loads.
Or just put the code inside a function.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is not what your instructor had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not used with that purpose.

If you need a javascript call to the backend server, then you make an AJAX call.

In your case you should just call your `validateForm()` method.

Comment: the validateForm function is in a js file on my server..I have just located the function which does the validation.so how can i use Ajax to call that function validateForm

Comment: You can't, unless your server is running node.js. You should instead just include the script on your page... `<script src="thejsfile.js"></script>`